# better-sqlite3 SqliteError: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to get my username and password hash into my SQLite database, but I always get the error message: SqliteError: NOT NULL constraint failed: Users.id

This error indicates that my query is not matching my Users table, but I can't find the issue.

My dump for Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Users" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "username" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "hash" varchar(60) NOT NULL
);
```

My Node code:

```
var Database = require('better-sqlite3')
var db = new Database('db.sqlite')

var sql = 'INSERT INTO Users (username, hash) VALUES (?,?)'
db.prepare(sql).run(username, hash)
```

The id field is set to be an autoincrementing integer and the primary key, therefore it should set itself automatically for every new entry.
The error message says that the NOT NULL contraint on Users.id failed, but id doesn't even have the NOT NULL constraint defined.

If I instead use the command

```
INSERT INTO Users (username, hash) VALUES ('testname','testhash1234');
```

directly in the SQLite3 database it all works fine.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in better-sqlite3?
How can I get around this problem?

Comment: PRIMARY KEY implies NOT NULL here, but in any case, NULL should result in the autoincremented value. I'd guess your dump is from a different database file.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice I had the wrong file open in my terminal.. derp..